# mongodb/gridfs java-driver use with utf-8 meta data

Tags: utf-8, mongodb, gridfs

I am trying to use GridFS to load a file along with some meta data 
using the java-driver. (2.5.3) 
Things work fine as long as the meta-data is in ASCII. But I get an 
exception  - the moment I try and set a UTF8 string with non ascii 
characters. 
String MetaData = "学海"; 
GridFS gridFS = new GridFS(db); 
GridFSInputFile inputFile = myFS.createFile(new File(filePath)); 
            DBObject dbObj = inputFile.getMetaData() 
            dbObj.put("metaData", MetaData);   ----> Get exception here (if non- ascii data)

```
        inputFile.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use UTF8 strings when storing regular documents?

Based on your description, it sounds like you're trying to report a bug rather than ask a question.

MongoDB uses a JIRA system for [reporting bugs](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA). If you can include the code you are using this will help the driver developer correct the issue.